# Dispatch queue specific usage for Swift and Objective C inter-op

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am migrating my project from ObjC to Swift. I have this code:

```
const char *specific = "my_queue"

dispatch_queue_set_specific(myQueue, specific, (void *)specific, NULL);
```

Later in my unit test, I have:

```
assertTrue(dispatch_get_specific(specific))
```

I noticed that in Swift, the API has changed, and we can't use any key type anymore

```
let value = String(cString: specific, encoding: .utf8)
myQueue.setSpecific(DispatchSpecificKey<String>(), value)
```

The 2 APIs already diverged. In ObjC, key and values are both c strings; but in Swift the key is a special type `DispatchSpecificKey` which is not available in ObjC.

So how can I set the specific in Swift, and get the correct specific from ObjC?

Another way around seems problematic too: how can I set the specific in ObjC, and get the correct specific from Swift?

Comment: What's the purpose of the code? Are you trying to "prove" you're on the correct queue?

Comment: @matt yep. Most of the "prove" happen in Unit test, but sometimes I put assert in non-test code as well. Right now all of them are in objc. I'm just starting to gradually migrate to Swift

Comment: “In ObjC, key and values are both c strings” … Just to clarify, the key is just a pointer. As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452967-dispatch_queue_set_specific) say: “Keys are only compared as pointers and are never dereferenced. Thus, you can use a pointer to a static variable for a specific subsystem or any other value that allows you to identify the value uniquely. Specifying a pointer to a string constant is not recommended.”

Comment: See [the libDispatch source](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/87ba47313b694222a5dc830eef40ac3863fd244d/src/swift/Queue.swift#L469) for example of how to get the pointer reference from the `DispatchSpecificKey`.

Comment: if it's any pointer, then what pointer should I use if c string is discouraged?

Comment: From the link I think I know how to get the pointer to DispatchSpecificKey. This will be useful if I set it in swift, then retrieve the content in ObjC. However not useful the other way around - how to get a DispatchSpecificKey from a raw C pointer.

Comment: “if it's any pointer, then what pointer should I use if c string is discouraged?” … Your `const char *` is fine: My point was merely that the salient part is the `const *` part, not that it was pointing to a C string. I was just attempting to disabuse you of the notion that in ObjC that it must be a C string. Nope. Just a pointer. It’s the address that you point to that is salient, not what that static pointer happens to point to.

Comment: Re `DispatchSpecificKey` from raw C pointer, I don’t see how one would do that. So, I’d suggest that until you port the Objective-C `dispatch_queue_set_specific`-related code to Swift, that you just implement an Objective-C function that performs the `dispatch_queue_get_specific` and/or `dispatch_get_specific` test, and call that wrapper function from Swift, rather than trying `DispatchSpecificKey` interoperability.

Comment: Is it possible to fake the pointer as `DIspatchSpecificKey`? something like cpp's reinterpret cast?

Answer (score 1):

It's a strange way how to do this. You need to create a DispatchSpecificKey object. Let's say you have a class User, and you want to store a User object with several DispatchQueues. You create ONE DispatchSpecificKey object with the type of the item you want to store:

```
let userKey = DispatchSpecificKey<User>()
```

And then you can use this key to store and read user object. The important thing is that you MUST stash userKey away somewhere and use it everywhere you want to set or get this specific value.

```
queue.setSpecific(userKey, User(name: "Smith", firstName: "John"))
let user = queue.getSpecific(userKey)
```

Here's the completely wrong way to do it:

```
queue.setSpecific(DispatchUserKey(), User(name: "Smith", firstName: "John"))
```

It's wrong because you lost the DispatchUserKey object, so you cannot get the value again.

Now lets say you have some (interesting) DispatchQueues that all want to store a "seller" and a "buyer" of type Person. Then you would write

```
let sellerKey = DispatchUserKey<Person>()
let buyerKey = DispatchUsrKey<Person>()

let buyer = ...
let seller = ...
let queue = ...

queue.setSpecificKey (key: sellerKey, value: seller)
queue.setSpecificKey (key: buyerKey, value: buyer)
```

Later you want to use the buyer of the current queue:

```
if let buyer = DispatchKey.getSpecificKey (key: buyerKey) {
    // Do something with the buyer
} else {
    // Sorry, no buyer in the current queue.
}
```

And you need to stash these two keys away somewhere where you can always get to them.